# SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID is empty

Tags: bash, slurm

I'm new in SLURM & Cloud computing.

I wrote a bash script which use job parallelisation with array mechanism. The problem is that I try to use the SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID environment variable available in SLURM to get the task's id back but this variable is empty and thus there are errors in the arithmetic operations .

Here is the bash code.

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --job-name=Distributed Raytracing
#SBATCH --time=01:00
#SBATCH --array=0-5

cd ./povray

SF=$((${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}*10+1))
EF=$((${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}*10+10))
./povray +A +W100 +H100 +Lshare/povray-3.6/include/ +SF$SF +EF$EF glsbng.ini
```

And here the output errors.

```
/var/spool/slurm/job01706/slurm_script: line 10: *10+1: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "*10+1")
/var/spool/slurm/job01706/slurm_script: line 11: *10+10: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "*10+10")
```

What's wrong ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

After several researches and tests, I found the problem comes from SLURM. When I submit the script with sbatch, only one job with one task is launched instead of one job with six tasks like expected. Thus the SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID isn't initialises because there is only one task in the job. The source of the problem comes from the first #SBATCH option because the name given to the job contains a space. Because of this space I think that SLURM doesn't interpret the other options and so the script is launched with the default options.

I just replaced

```
#SBATCH --job-name=Distributed Raytracing
```

with

```
#SBATCH --job-name=DistributedRaytracing
```

and there are now no errors.

I ask me now why SLURM doesn't show an error when there is a such error (space in the name), and why the others options aren't interpreted ?

Comment: alternatively you can use quotes: `#SBATCH --job-name="Distributed Raytracing"`